# error on table import : key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql

so im working on a website , i did some changes to one of tables on my localhost so naturally i want to replace that table on the live server

so i deleted the table on the server 
now im trying to to import table from my localhost to my live server here is the 
 exported .sql file content from my localhost

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 17, 2018 at 06:28 PM
-- Server version: 5.7.14
-- PHP Version: 7.0.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `skywin_mock`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `lottery_winners`
--

CREATE TABLE `lottery_winners` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `lottery_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `credit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rew_type` char(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `lottery_winners`
--
ALTER TABLE `lottery_winners`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `lottery_winners_user_id_lottery_id_unique` (`user_id`,`lottery_id`),
  ADD KEY `lottery_winners_lottery_id_foreign` (`lottery_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `lottery_winners`
--
ALTER TABLE `lottery_winners`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `lottery_winners`
--
ALTER TABLE `lottery_winners`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `lottery_winners_lottery_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`lottery_id`) REFERENCES `lotteries` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `lottery_winners_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

but i keep getting this error

```
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `skywin_mock`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `lottery_winners`
--

CREATE TABLE `lottery_winners` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `lottery_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `credit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rew_type` char(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table `database`.`lottery_winners` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)
```

there are 2 forign keys on the code which their table exist on the live server

here is sum dummy text becuz SO doesnt let me to post this question without some details .... but i think its pretty clear what the problem is

Comment: You probably have some foreign key pointing to that table. If you recreate that table, it needs to have the index on the referenced column at the moment you create the table. So either drop the foreign key and recreate if later, or add the index (probably `lottery_winners_lottery_id_foreign`, maybe the primary key) directly with the table, not with an `alter table` afterwards.

Comment: @Solarflare thanx , as you said there were some other tables pointing to the lottery_winners .. pleas post your suggestion as answer so i can select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While disabling [foreign key checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) allows you to drop tables that are referenced by foreign keys of other tables, when you recreate the table, the foreign key has to be correctly defined at that moment:

> When re-creating a table that was dropped, an error is returned if the table definition does not conform to the foreign key constraints referencing the table.

This includes that any index that is required for these foreign keys to work have to exist in the table definition.

So add the indexes (or at least the one you need for the foreign key) directly to the the table definition, not with an alter table statement afterwards:

```
CREATE TABLE `lottery_winners` (
   ... ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `lottery_winners_user_id_lottery_id_unique` (`user_id`,`lottery_id`),
   KEY `lottery_winners_lottery_id_foreign` (`lottery_id`)
) ENGINE=...
```

(You might as well add the two foreign keys to `users` and `lotteries` here too, of course, and set `id` to `auto_increment`).

An alternative way is to remove the foreign keys referencing that table, recreate (and alter) the table, reenable foreign key checks (if you haven't already) and then recreate the foreign keys. This process can help to verify that you e.g. didn't miss to reinsert a required row (if you maybe didn't clear the other tables that hold the foreign key), as otherwise

> Setting foreign_key_checks to 1 does not trigger a scan of the existing table data. Therefore, rows added to the table while foreign_key_checks=0 will not be verified for consistency.